# Computer stalling on boot after updating xorg.conf.d

Tags: ubuntu, boot, xorg, nvidia

My brightness function keys weren't working, so I followed the suggestion in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1247820/1103141). I updated, saved, rebooted--now my computer has completely stalled in the boot.

The only extra thing I did was put an extra line in between the two chunks of text (i.e. between what was there and what I appended). Could that have caused this?

Ultimately, I don't know how or why that happened. I also don't seem to have a safe mode to boot into. How can I fix this? I am running Ubuntu 20.04 on an Asus TUF A15.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Power off computer. Power on. Wait till GRUB will show where you can choose which Linux distro you want to run. Choose the one which di not start, press e. Navigate down with the arrow-down key until you can see a line ending with:

```
ro   quiet splash $vt_handoff
```

Using your keyboard replace the following keywords.
FROM:

```
ro   quiet splash $vt_handoff
```

TO:

```
rw init=/bin/bash
```

Then when it will start type:

```
mount -o remount,rw /sysroot/
```

Next type

```
mount -a
```

Next type:

```
chroot /sysroot/
```

Then to check is it mounted type

```
mount
```

Then revert the change you made. For example:

If you performed a change in /etc/default/grub to disable the acpi by adding acpi=off revert the change and then perform the command"

```
grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
```

Next type

```
 reboot
```

And check does it start normally.

Comment: Thanks. As it happens, once I used `rw init /bin/bash`, the `mount -o remount,rw /sysroot/` didn't find anything. But I was able to open `xorg` file in `nano` and simply delete the offending lines. On restart the system functioned completely normally.

Comment: mount -o remount,rw /sysroot/ remounts the root file system into read write mode, which let to modify files. Without this it is impossible to modify files, because the system is mounted always in read only mode after each failure, when it is impossible to boot. Why? Just in case, to avoid the situation when files will be overwritten to let system administrator perform a backup image for example of the damaged system , restore the backup somewhere else and repair it there. This command does not find anything. I hope I explained it well.